# Blender opencv-python dllLoadError

Tags: python, opencv, blender

I'm using Blender 2.78 (64bit) with Python 3.5.2 on Windows 7 (64bit). My situation is that I want to use opencv in combination with python in Blender. I went in serious trouble trying so and was working for days without any obvious success..

However from googling I found that there is a way to install pip as a module for blenders python and with pip I was able to install modules such as numpy oder scipy. This indeed also worked with opencv as it got successfully installed (including positive checks). It looked fine. But as I tried to import cv2 in a Console in Blender I got the error like the thread starter above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\python\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I then tried to start blender python in an external shell and retried the import process resulting in the same error.

Next was retrying the complete procedure for my system python (same version 3.5.2) and everything worked perfectly.

From now on I was a bit confused as "pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python" towards opencv-python states that everything is linked statically and everything you have to do is what I have done. Looking in the FAQ the error is mentioned. You get the advise to check visual c++ redistributable and c runtime library. I did so, however, both is up to date and on system python opencv works perfectly that way.

Next try. As the system python works perfectly with opencv I removed blender python and pasted a copy of the system python instead. According to "blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules"
this is an alternative from using blenders own python.

Numpy, Scipy imports work perfectly. Importing cv2 leads to the same error as before.

If I now start the system-python copy that now is blenders python from a command shell cv2 can be imported.

Where is the difference here in the environment blender creates and the one from the shell??

I have installed a tool named listDlls to list all the dlls loaded by specific processes in order to compare blender-python and python. You can see some differences but I dont understand the matter of those except from the absence of the cv2 pyd in blenders python.

Any ideas?

First list is the python-process list, second the blender list:
https://ufile.io/uidy1
https://ufile.io/1eshi

Comment: You say that opencv-python is statically linked - blender also uses opencv, loading different lib versions would conflict, maybe loading two copies of the same library can also conflict. Can cv2 be built using the same dll as blender? Could blender be built without opencv to use cv2? What about using pyopencv?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! pyopencv is not available for my python version. I will check the other options as soon as possible..

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I wont get hands on it in the near future..